# Import JSON file into SQL Server table - getting an error

Tags: jquery, json, sql-server, import

I am trying to import my JSON file into a SQL Server 2019 table using this query:

```
DECLARE  @JSON varchar(max)

SELECT @JSON = bulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'E:\mytestfile.json' , SINGLE_CLOB) import

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (@JSON)
WITH (   
    [id] int,
    [data_joined]int,
    [email] varchar(100),
    [first_name] varchar(100),
    [last_login_date] int   
)
```

However, when I execute the query I got this error when importing the file into a SQL Server table:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Incorrect syntax near '@JSON'
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Looking forward to assistance for my problem!

Thank you!

Comment: `FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)` instead of **OPENROWSET**(@JSON)

Comment: Thanks for your quick assistance!

after replacing the phrase with  {FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)} the first error has been disappeared :)

Comment: However I am still getting the second error message, if you could help?
(((((((Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.)))))))))))

Comment: You can actually merge these two queries together using `CROSS APPLY`, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53d87a54aa5450fc57e550884071b8d4. Either way the variable should be `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 and 2022 on the horizon - so which one is it really, that you're using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2019 ( sorry for typo mistake)

Comment: it's working now, and the error got disappeared, However the query return only one row!
How to get all the JSON rows into SQL table?
@Charlieface Thanks for your assistance !

Comment: Without sample data we cannot help